# How can I set up video files so that, if a film is foreign, the subtitles automatically play?

Tags: video-editor

How can I set up video files so that, if a film is foreign, the subtitles automatically play, whereas the subtitles remain dormant if a film isn't foreign?

The reason I ask is because I'm in the process of learning a language, and might want to learn other languages in the future, so I'll keep certain subtitles for films of my native language. However, I don't want to have to disable subtitles every time I watch a film in my native language, and I don't want to have to enable subtitles every time I watch a foreign film.

I read somewhere else that I could insert an empty subtitle file as the default track, which is a great idea, yet I can't find any information anywhere explaining how to do this.vi I've tried creating an empty .txt file and then changing its format to .srt, but this doesn't fly on MKVToolNix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a video on YT.

1. Open notepad
2. Type "0" on the first line
3. Type "00:00:00.00 --> 00:00:00.00" on the second line
4. Save as .srt file type

Now you have an empty .SRT file that MKVToolNix accepts.

You can also edit the file order and the default audio/video files in the program itself.